# Display problem for my custom tab in ADD/EDIT product page (admin)

Tags: product, layout, adminhtml

I have implemented a new tab in the ADD/EDIT product page in admin using this tutorial: http://www.magentothemess.com/archives/1267

It is working, but in the ADD product case, my tab is displayed in the 2 steps:
- the one were you select the product type (generally only 1 tab is displayed called Options)
- the second step were you have all the tabs (general, prices, etc..)

How can I do to display my custom tab only at the second step?

here is my .xml

```
<layout>

    <adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>Formula_price_tab</name>
                <block>quotemodule/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>

    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>Formula_price_tab</name>
                <block>quotemodule/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

Comment: What happen if you remove `<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>  ... </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Add Custom Tabs To The Magento Product Admin](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/)

Change your layout to

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>Formula_price_tab</name>
                <block>quotemodule/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

Comment: that is what I did first, but in that case, my tab is not displayed at all while creating the product...

Comment: can you add some screen shot?

Comment: the first "Add product step":[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/mkw35t.png[/IMG]
The second step: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/ndx2ki.png[/IMG]
My tab (Formula Price Type) is present on both… I would like it to be displayed only in the second step.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the method `canShowTab()` in your tab block and make it look like this:

```
public function canShowTab() {
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if ($product->getId()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!$product->getAttributeSetId()) {
        return false;
    }
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    if ($request->getParam('type') == 'configurable') {
        if ($request->getParam('attributes')) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```